# PDFs not opening correctly in FireFox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, pdf, adobe-reader

Windows 7

Firefox 3.6

Adobe Reader 9

Whenever I try to open PDFs in FireFox, I sometimes get a message box with no title and no text, just an "OK" button.  I have to refresh the page multiple times to get the PDF to display correctly.  Is there a fix for this?

Comment: All I can say is to remove Adobe Reader Firefox add-on and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, like divided said, uninstall and reinstall the Adobe Reader Firefox add-on. OR, you could try FoxitReader and its add-on, it works better than Adobe Reader, in my opinion.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the firefox addon and I updated adobe reader from 9.3.2 to 9.4.1.  This has not fixed the problem.  Unfortunately, I can't use another PDF reader since this is in a corporate environment.

Comment: Hm... Try the following:
 - Uninstall Firefox, and install its later version (3.6.13, if I'm not mistaken);
 - Uninstall Acrobat Reader again, and reinstall it.

If possible, uninstall all the above using a program like 'Revo Uninstaller', using Full Removal. This was, everything is erased (even registry settings).